# I have following format of posting data to server. I want to post these data to server using volley library

Tags: android, android-studio

```
data: {
"friends" : 
    [
        "number" :  
            [
                "9803002718",
                "+977 9803002318",
                "155297655",
                "977 1 552987"
            ],
        "email" :   
            [
                "xx@gamil.com",
                "yy@gamil.com",
                "xx@gamil.com"
            ]
    ],
"updated_at" : "2016-10-16 13:01:01"}
```

Hi i am new to android. I have to post the above values as parameters.

I don't know where to even start. I can make **simple string request using volley**. But the about parameters consists of a key **"number"** which has **all the contacts** from the users phone. I can retrieve the contact using `ContentResolver`.

The key **"email"** has the list of **all the emails**. Now both the phone number and email are store in another map with key **"friends"**. finally the whole data is kept in another map with key **"data"**.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid..!!

Comment: i know this is not well json formatted, but this is the format i need to send the parameters to the server. Do you have any idea how it can be done? I have sent the parameter from postman and it gives me the desired response too.

Comment: I am not talking about format. It is not valid & **You can only build valid JSON from Java so this type of JSON cannot be created in JAVA.**

Comment: oh thanks @jankigadhiya. Much appreciated

Comment: if possible could you edit the above json into a valid format and post it?? That would be a huge help for me. My main task is to send contacts to the server (which i assume you have already figured it out (: ). The above json format work on iOs and has been successfully deployed as well. I need to do it on android as well so if you could help me on this one I would be greatly Thankful @jankigadhiya

Comment: I have edited the question but the edit got rejected. I can post valid JSON as a answer if you want ??

Comment: yes! please. That would be really helpful

Comment: Posted it.. Please refer..!!